# How can I login and access to my Django-Rest-Framework while running my Nuxt project local?

Tags: vuejs2, django-rest-framework, axios, nuxt.js

I use Django-Rest-Framework for my API. It is on a remote server in the internet.

Locally I have a Nuxt-JS application running which should consume the REST-API.

How can I access this API from my local machine?

1) I would like to get the CSRF token from my login page with axios. For example from: /accounts/login/
For this I would like to make a "GET" call and geht from the HTTP-HEADER my CSRF tocken. But how?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [@nuxt/auth](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module) module after which you can update your nuxt.config.js file as follows:

```
auth: {
   redirect: {
      login: 'your-login-redirect-path',
      logout: 'your-logout-redirect-path',
      home: 'your-home-path'
   },
   strategies: {
      local: {
         endpoints: {
            login: { url: 'your-django-login-endpoint', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
            logout: { url: 'your-django-logout-endpoint', method: 'post' },
            user: { url: 'your-django-userinfo-endpoint', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' }
         }
      }
   }
},
```

Check out [Nuxt Auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) for more info

Comment: But I don't have tokens. I just want to use the default authentication. 
Where can i configure the CSRF token etc. I guess this is not possible?

Comment: Nuxt uses token based authentication; moreover, I am not sure that nuxt can be used with django in that way.

Comment: Why? If I can do this with curl it should be no problem to use it with nuxt?

Comment: In that case, I think you should try adding your CSRF token to axios header.

Comment: So I guess it is not possible. Because I can not access the set-cookie header from the response: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/295#issuecomment-381485257